# Fastest way to select a valid range for raster data

Tags: r, r-raster

Using R, I need to select the valid range for a given raster (from package `raster`) in the fastest possible way. I tried this:

```
library(raster)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(compiler)

r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))

#Let's see if precompiling helps speed...
f <- function(x, min, max) reclassify(x, c(-Inf, min, NA, max, Inf, NA))
g <- cmpfun(f)

#Benchmark!
compare <- microbenchmark(
    calc(r, fun=function(x){ x[x < 0.2] <- NA; x[x > 0.8] <- NA; return(x)}), 
    reclassify(r, c(-Inf, 0.2, NA, 0.8, Inf, NA)),
    g(r, 0.2, 0.8),
    times=100)
autoplot(compare) #Reclassify is much faster, precompiling doesn't help much.

#Check they are the same...
identical(
          calc(r, fun=function(x){ x[x < 0.2] <- NA; x[x > 0.8] <- NA; return(x)}),
          reclassify(r, c(-Inf, 0.2, NA, 0.8, Inf, NA))
) #TRUE
identical(
          reclassify(r, c(-Inf, 0.2, NA, 0.8, Inf, NA)),
          g(r, 0.2, 0.8),
) #TRUE
```

[image: Benchmark]

The reclassify method is much faster, but I'm sure that it can be sped up more. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one more way:

```
h <- function(r, min, max) {
  rr <- r[]
  rr[rr < min | rr > max] <- NA
  r[] <- rr
  r
}

i <- cmpfun(h)

identical(
  i(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  g(r, 0.2, 0.8)
)



#Benchmark!
compare <- microbenchmark(
  calc(r, fun=function(x){ x[x < 0.2] <- NA; x[x > 0.8] <- NA; return(x)}), 
  reclassify(r, c(-Inf, 0.2, NA, 0.8, Inf, NA)),
  g(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  h(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  i(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  times=100)
autoplot(compare)
```

Compiling doesn't help much in this instance.

[image]

You could even gain some further speed up, by accessing slots of the raster object directly using `@` (although usually discouraged).

```
j <- function(r, min, max) {
  v <- r@data@values
  v[v < min | v > max] <- NA
  r@data@values <- v
  r
}

k <- cmpfun(j)

identical(
  j(r, 0.2, 0.8)[],
  g(r, 0.2, 0.8)[]
)
```

[image]

Comment: That is a brilliant answer. Thanks!

Comment: function `j` is indeed discouraged as it will fail in many cases. It is unfortunate that you divulge such bad practice

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer to this question is true for the example raster, it is important to note that the fastest safe function is highly dependent on raster size: the functions `h` and `i` presented by @rengis are only faster with relatively small rasters (and relatively simple reclassifications).  Just increasing the size of the raster `r` in the OP's example by a magnitude of ten makes `reclassify` quicker:

```
# Code from OP @AF7
library(raster)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(compiler)

#Let's see if precompiling helps speed...
f <- function(x, min, max) reclassify(x, c(-Inf, min, NA, max, Inf, NA))
g <- cmpfun(f)

# Funcions from @rengis
h <- function(r, min, max) {
  rr <- r[]
  rr[rr < min | rr > max] <- NA
  r[] <- rr
  r
}

i <- cmpfun(h)

# Benchmark with larger raster (100k cells, vs 10k originally)
r <- raster(ncol = 1000, nrow = 100)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))

compare <- microbenchmark(
  calc(r, fun=function(x){ x[x < 0.2] <- NA; x[x > 0.8] <- NA; return(x)}), 
  reclassify(r, c(-Inf, 0.2, NA, 0.8, Inf, NA)),
  g(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  h(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  i(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  times=100)
autoplot(compare)
```

[image: Benchmark results with 100k-cell raster]

The exact point when `reclassify` becomes quicker is dependent both on the number of the cells in the raster and on the complexity of the reclassification, but in this case the cross-over point is at about 50,000 cells (see below).

As the raster becomes even larger (or the calculation more complex), another way to speed up reclassification is using multi-threading, e.g. with the `snow` package:

```
# Reclassify, using clusterR to split into two threads
library(snow)
tryCatch({
      beginCluster(n = 2)
      clusterR(r, reclassify, args = list(rcl = c(-Inf, 0.2, NA, 0.8, Inf, NA)))
    }, finally = endCluster())
```

Multi-threading involves even more overhead to set up, and so only makes sense with very large rasters and/or more complex calculations (in fact, I was surprised to note that it didn't come out as the best option under any of the conditions I tested below--perhaps with a more complex reclassification?).

To illustrate, I've plotted results from microbenchmark using the OP's setup at intervals up to 10 million cells (10 runs of each) below:

[image: Benchmark results, runtime vs raster size]

As a final note, compiling didn't make a difference at any of the tested sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The raster package has a function for that: `clamp`. It is faster than `g` but slower than `h` and `i` because it has some overhead (safety) built in.

```
compare <- microbenchmark(
  h(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  i(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  clamp(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  g(r, 0.2, 0.8),
  times=100)
autoplot(compare)
```

Comment: I knew that `raster` had something like that, and I simply forgot it. Damn me. Can you provide an example on why the above function `j` is discouraged?

Comment: Function `j` won't work if a Raster* object is created from a file on disk, as there will not be any values in `@data@values`. Setting new values directly messes up the internally stored min and max values (but that does not necessarily break things)

Comment: excellent, thanks for the clarification. I am honestly unsure which  answer to accept now: your is more exact, but @rengis provided `h` which is the fastest function (while keeping decently safe).