# Raster image goes below base layer, while markers stay above: xIndex is ignored

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm building a simple Shiny + Leaflet R application to navigate a map over which a `raster` (from package `raster`) is plotted with the useful `addRasterImage()` function. The code is heavily based on Leaflet's own examples. However, I'm encountering some problems with layering: the raster image is somehow rendered below the tiles every time I reload the tiles, even if I set a negative `zIndex`. This does not happen for markers. See the attached code. Example input file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlZ3Tjj36sNWUdSRnRpcFpacU0/view?usp=sharing), 366KB.

```
####
###### YOU CAN SKIP THIS, THE PROBLEM LIES BELOW ######
####

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(raster)

selrange <- function(r, min, max) {  #Very fast way of selecting raster range, even faster than clamp.
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064738/fastest-way-to-select-a-valid-range-for-raster-data
  rr <- r[]
  rr[rr < min | rr > max] <- NA
  r[] <- rr
  r
}

llflood <- raster("example_flooding_posmall.nc")
ext <- extent(llflood)
flood <- projectRasterForLeaflet(llflood)
floodmin <- cellStats(flood, min)
floodmax <- cellStats(flood, max)

tiles <- c("Hydda.Base",
       "Hydda.Full",
       "Esri.WorldImagery",
       "Esri.WorldTopoMap"
)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
    sliderInput("range", "Return Period (years)", floor(floodmin), ceiling(floodmax),
      value = c(floor(floodmin), ceiling(floodmax)), step = 1
    ),
    selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",
      rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
    ),
    selectInput("tiles", "Background",
      tiles
    ),
    checkboxInput("legend", "Show legend", TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    selrange(flood, input$range[1], input$range[2])
  })

  # This reactive expression represents the palette function,
  # which changes as the user makes selections in UI.
  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric(input$colors, values(filteredData()), na.color = NA)
  })

  ######
  ###### THE INTERESTING PART IS HERE ######
  ######

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that
    # won't need to change dynamically (at least, not unless the
    # entire map is being torn down and recreated).
    leaflet()  %>%
      fitBounds(ext[1], ext[3], ext[2], ext[4])
  })

  observe({ #Observer to edit tiles
    selectedTiles <- input$tiles
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearTiles() %>%
      addProviderTiles(selectedTiles, providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10, continuousWorld=FALSE), group="base")
  })

  observe({ #Observer to edit colors and valid range
    filtdata <- filteredData()
    pal <- colorpal()
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearImages() %>%
      addRasterImage(filtdata, opacity=0.7, project=FALSE, colors=pal, group="overlay") %>%
      addMarkers(lng=8.380508, lat=45.18058, popup="This marker stays above, the raster sinks below every time I load a new tile set")
  })

  ######
  ###### THE INTERESTING PART ENDS HERE ######
  ######

  observe({ #Observer to show or hide the legend
    inputlegend <- input$legend
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    # Remove any existing legend, and only if the legend is
    # enabled, create a new one.
    proxy %>% clearControls()
    if (inputlegend) {
      pal <- colorpal()
      proxy %>% addLegend(position = "bottomright",
        pal = pal, values = values(filteredData()), opacity=1
      )
    }
  })

  cat("Clicked point:\tLon\t\tLat\t\tValue\n")
  observe({ #Observe to show clicked points
    x = as.double(unlist(input$map_click)[2])
    if(!is.null(x)) {
      y = unlist(input$map_click)[1]
      val = extract(llflood, cellFromXY(llflood, c(x, y)))
      if (!is.na(val)) cat("\t\t", x, "\t", y, "\t", val, "\n")
    }
  })

}

## RUN:
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too have this problem, but your question is the only reference to it I can find.

The only workaround I could find was to also redraw the tiles in the raster observer e.g.

```
observe({ #Observer to edit colors and valid range
  selectedTiles <- input$tiles
  filtdata <- filteredData()
  pal <- colorpal()
  leafletProxy("map") %>%
  clearTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(selectedTiles, providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10, continuousWorld=FALSE), group="base")
  clearImages() %>%
  addRasterImage(filtdata, opacity=0.7, project=FALSE, colors=pal, group="overlay") %>%
  addMarkers(lng=8.380508, lat=45.18058, popup="This marker stays above, the raster sinks below every time I load a new tile set")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if anyone else is still having issues with this, but I finally found a way to get the raster layer to stay on top of the basemap. As an update to the original code provided by the OP:

```
leaflet()  %>%
  fitBounds(ext[1], ext[3], ext[2], ext[4]) %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = selectedTiles,
                   overlayGroups = "overlay",
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE, autoZIndex = FALSE))
```

By including the argument `autoZindex = FALSE` in addition to setting `addProviderTiles(selectedTiles, providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10))`, the raster stays on top.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem, with three provider layers added statically and 2 raster layers added dynamically later on.  Originally, the raster layers were hidden below the provider tiles.  I found @jcullens answer above resolved the problem well.  Here is my working code, incorporating their suggestion:

```
 # show the world map
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({leaflet(options=leafletOptions(minZoom=5, maxZoom=24)) %>%
      addTiles(group='Street Map')  %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenTopoMap, group='Topography', providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10)) %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group='Satellite', providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10)) %>% 
      leafem::addMouseCoordinates() %>%
      setView(lat = 54.196396, lng =-4.411267, zoom=5) %>%
      setMaxBounds(lat1 = 48.835948, lng1 =-11.511216, lat2 = 61.639102, lng2 =2.668653) %>% 
      addLayersControl(position='bottomleft', 
        baseGroups = c('Street Map', 'Topography', 'Satellite', 'None'),
        overlayGroups= c('AOI boundary', 'Biomass', 'Land Use', 'NTM', 'Grid'),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE, autoZIndex = FALSE)) %>% 
      hideGroup(c('AOI boundary', 'Biomass', 'Land Use', 'NTM', 'Grid'))
  })
```

At lines 4-5, I added `, providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10)` and at line 12, `options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE, autoZIndex = FALSE)`.  This solved the problem, with the raster layers (Biomass, Land Use) now always appearing on top of the background tiles.  This remains true as the layers are switched on or off.