# addRasterImage not rendering on leaflet shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, mapping, leaflet, r-leaflet

So I am trying to dynamically show some raster layers i have previously computed. I need to update the values shown on the markers and the displayed image.
It works fine with the markers, but it doesnt seem to do anything with the addRasterImage command. Any help? Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

#### Mapa en shiny ####
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                sliderInput("range", "Fecha", 1, length(arch),
                            value = 1, step = 1
                )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  # filteredData <- reactive({
  #   a[[input$range]]
  # })

  int.pred<-cropinterp@data@values[!is.na(cropinterp@data@values)]
  pal<-colorNumeric("RdBu", int.pred)
  pal2<- pal<-colorNumeric("Spectral", (int.pred))

  neess<- seq(1,1000,1)
  qpal <- colorBin(terrain.colors(4), domain=neess, bins=c(1,10,100,1000,Inf))

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that
    # won't need to change dynamically (at least, not unless the
    # entire map is being torn down and recreated).
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles(group="OSM (default)") %>%
      setView(lng=-3.77 , lat =40.36, zoom=6) %>%
      addMeasure()%>%
      addRasterImage(rr, colors="Spectral", opacity = 0.7, group ="Krige de Precios") %>%
      addRasterImage(cropinterp, colors="Spectral", opacity = 0.7, group = "Spline de Precios") %>%
      addPolylines(data = cropcont, fillOpacity=0.5, fillColor = "transparent",opacity = 0.7,weight = 2, group = "Contorno Precios") %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("OSM (default)"),
        overlayGroups = c("Contorno Precios", "Spline de Precios", "Krige de Precios","Spline Madrid"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE),
        position="topleft") %>%
      addLegend("bottomright", pal=pal2, values=int.pred, title = "Precio", opacity = 1)%>%
      addLegend(pal = qpal, values = neess, opacity = 1, position="bottomleft")

  })
  # Incremental changes to the map (in this case, replacing the
  # circles when a new color is chosen) should be performed in
  # an observer. Each independent set of things that can change
  # should be managed in its own observer.
  observeEvent(input$range, {
    nn<- input$range
      leafletProxy("map", session)%>%
      clearMarkers()%>%
      clearMarkerClusters()%>%
      addCircleMarkers(lat = timeline$Latitud, lng = timeline$Longitud..WGS84., fillColor = pal,
                       label = paste(as.character(timeline$Rótulo), timeline[,nn+9]),
                       labelOptions = labelOptions(opacity = 0.9,noHide = T), 
                      clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), group = "OSM (default)")
  })

  observe({
    na<- input$range
    leafletProxy("map", session)%>%
      addRasterImage(a[[na]], opacity = 0.7)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Apparently the code doesn't react to this bit:

```
observe({
        na<- input$range
        leafletProxy("map", session)%>%
          addRasterImage(a[[na]], opacity = 0.7)
      })
```

Answer (score 3):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

After **a lot of digging** I found an answer to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159578/raster-image-goes-below-base-layer-while-markers-stay-above-xindex-is-ignored)

The problem was that the Raster Image was rendered *below* the tiles (dunno why the hell that happens but it has been a real bugger). On the answer provided on the linked question, the user resolves it by removing the tiles and adding them dynamically each time the input changes:

```
tiles <- c("Hydda.Base",
           "Hydda.Full",
           "Esri.WorldImagery",
           "Esri.WorldTopoMap")

  observe({
    filtdata <- filteredData()
    selectedTiles <- input$tiles
    leafletProxy("map", session)%>%
      clearTiles() %>%
      addProviderTiles(selectedTiles, providerTileOptions(zIndex=-10, continuousWorld=FALSE), group="base")%>%
      clearImages() %>%
      addRasterImage(filtdata, colors="Spectral", project=FALSE, opacity = 0.7, group = "Spline Madrid")
  })
```